# How to automatically backup a ratio of a table based on one column?

Tags: sql, mysql, oracle-xe

I want to automatically backup a database so I have two databases, one with all data and the other with a ratio of each table -i.e. 20%- based on a column.

Comment: Please be more specific. What's a ratio of each table?

Comment: I mean ratio of data in a table

Comment: So you want, say, 20% of the rows from each table? I can understand that, although I'd discourage you from doing it. What I'm not sure about is what you mean by "based on a column".

Comment: I mean for example to add row in the second table where the value of some column exceeds for example 1000 until it reaches 20%

Comment: Sample data would be helpful. (Edit your question to include sample data.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my first try.

```
create table t1 (
id integer primary key,
val integer not null);

create table t2 (
id integer primary key,
val integer not null);

insert into t1 values (1,1000);
insert into t1 values (2,1000);
insert into t1 values (3,1000);
insert into t1 values (4,1000);
insert into t1 values (5,1000);
insert into t1 values (6,1000);
insert into t1 values (7,1000);
insert into t1 values (8,1000);
insert into t1 values (9,1000);
insert into t1 values (10,1000);
insert into t1 values (11,1000);

insert into t2
select id, val
from t1
where (val >= 1000) 
  and (rownum <= cast((0.2 * (select count(*) from t1)) as integer));
```

Comment: My first answer is 'Unknown column 'rownum' in WHERE clause'

Comment: @Mchl: "rownum" is Oracle syntax. I think the MySQL syntax uses "LIMIT" in this specific context. I don't have MySQL installed to test it with.

Comment: @Mchl: And you'd probably have to use something like `LIMIT <expression>` instead of `LIMIT <= <expression>`.

Comment: That explains that. You can't use subqueries in LIMIT clause in MySQL if I recall correctly.

Comment: @Mchl: That expression just calculates the 20%. I looked at the MySQL documentation, and it seems to say that `LIMIT` requires two integer constants in a query. So you can't use any kind of expression here. But the docs seem to say that you can use parameters and local variables instead of integer constants *within a stored program*. (As of MySQL 5.5.6) So, to do this in MySQL, I think you'd have to write a stored program. But I could be wrong.

Comment: You could probably use a session variable, without creating a stored procedure.

Comment: @Mchl: I guess that depends on whether MySQL treats session variables as if they were constants. I can't say I'd be surprised either way.